# Как отправить свой контакт боту в telegram?

Tags: python, telebot, share, telethon

Я общаюсь с ботом со стороны клиента и в определённый момент требуется отправить свой контакт этому боту. в самом чате появляется кнопка "Передать контакт", после этого он и отправляется. В общем вопрос, как либо нажать на кнопку (она в поле ввода сообщения), либо отправить свой контакт боту?

Я использую библиотеку telethon на python

Answer (score 0):

Итак, проблему отправки контакта я решил тем, что пересылал свой контакт из своего же лс. А если вам нужно нажать на кнопку (CallBack) используйте это:

```
client(GetBotCallbackAnswerRequest(chat, message.id, message.reply_markup.rows[row].buttons[button].data))
```